# Pull request option missing

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have already make a pull request in this branch...
But I have made changes, add the respective files, commit them, push them to the origin and now I want to make the pull request but i don't see the option anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all what is your Git server (github? bitbulet? etc).

Whenever you open a `pull request` all the **changes** made on the selected branch in the pull request are **accumulated** into the original pull request as long as it's not merged or declined.

> now I want to make the pull request but i don't see the option anywhere

If your pull request was not merged your latest code (commits) should be listed under the pull request. You will not be able to open a new pull request until you will merge or decline the original pull request you created.

[image]